# Applied font style look and feel differs in different Android Devices

Tags: android, user-interface, fonts, styles

I have used Century Gothic as my font style in my app. In Samsung S4 it looks good and in Samsung Duos it looks bit different. The font looks like broken in Samsung Duos. Is there any way to this or what was the cause of this issue? Can anyone help me..

Comment: More info would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because different screens have different densities.
Give font size according to different screen densities in 'sp' units.

Eg:-

```
res/values/dimens.xml    
res/values-small/dimens.xml    
res/values-normal/dimens.xml    
res/values-xlarge/dimens.xml

//for small    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <dimen name="text_size">15sp</dimen>
</resources>

//for normal    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <dimen name="text_size">20sp</dimen>
</resources>

//for large    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <dimen name="text_size">30sp</dimen>
</resources>

//for xlarge    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <dimen name="text_size">40sp</dimen>
</resources>
```